# Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\app\aspnetapp.csproj]

Tags: docker

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/tree/master/aspnetapp

Docker command `docker build -t aspnetapp`.

I am getting an error for docker build command as

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.105\NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\app\aspnetapp.csproj]

[image: error message screenshot]

```
[1]PS C:\Users\pssharma\dotnet-docker-samples\aspnetapp> docker build -t aspnetapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.444MB
Step 1/10 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
 ---> eb21d939e0d8
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d4ec30216ed7
Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2ff39b5e6cb4
Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 776764a35311
  Restoring packages for C:\app\aspnetapp.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\app\aspnetapp.csproj...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.105\NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\app\asp
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.105\NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. [C:\app\aspnetapp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.105\NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   The operation timed out [C:\app\aspnetapp.csproj]
```

The following command returned a non-zero code: 1

```
powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; dotnet restore
```

[image: error message screenshot]

Comment: On few earlier versions I had to restart docker service to resolve issues like this. Could you try to restart it and retry the build from an administrator powershel consolel: `Restart-Service com.docker.service -Force`

Comment: Hi,I tried with Administrator PowerShell but getting same error.

Comment: Is there any way to check the logs for this.

Comment: You can try to add  `RUN curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -v` and `RUN dotnet restore --verbosity diag` in your DockerFile to see what it is doing - if only restore fails or both with curl too.

Comment: I getting same error this is Dockerfile                                                                              FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you resolved?

Comment: @iberodev did you get it resolved?

Comment: no @ParthTrivedi

Comment: @iberodev i get it fixes. My issue is with corporate firewall.

Comment: Which container are you using? Linux or Windows? 
I had same issue with windows container because I was using linux image

Comment: Do you have a corporate VPN running on your machine?

Comment: I had the same issue when i did `docker-compose build`. docker build could not connect to the public or private nuget feed. I had corp VPN enabled as well. then I did a `RUN curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -v`  step in the docker image and turned out corp firewall was breaking SSL apart. whitelisting the feed domains fixed it

Answer (score 37):

This appears to happen when there are multiple network adaptors present for the host and the priority of said adaptor is misconfigured. Run the following to display a table of your network adaptors:

```
Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4 | Sort-Object -Property InterfaceMetric -Descending
```

You want your primary adaptor (in my case wifi) to have the **lowest** InterfaceMetric.

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias 'Wi-Fi' -InterfaceMetric 1
```

My network adaptor table for reference:
[image]

See this github thread for more information:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2760#issuecomment-430889666

Comment: This works for me ! .NetCore sdk 3.1.300 web app, windows container. Try run powershell as Administrator. Check this out also : https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/09/how-to-fix-network-errors-with-docker-and-windows-containers/

Comment: I'm new to this docker business, and I'm stunned that this answer worked! And yes - RUN POWERSHELL AS ADMIN.

Also: "WiFi" wasn't hyphenated in my list - watch out folks @_@

Comment: This worked as a charm. I had two network adapters in my computer and they had wrong priorities. I had to "run it as administrator". This works!

Answer (score 18):

For me, this issue appeared randomly (along with multiple similar issues, such as "permission denied for nuget" etc. To fix that, restart Visual Studio)
For **windows**, it was fixed by restarting docker service and restarting Visual Studio (2017).

1. Shut down Docker and Visual Studio
2. Winkey + R, type in services.msc
3. Find Docker for Windows Service and restart it (restarting Docker normally is not enough)
4. Start Docker and Visual Studio

Comment: it worked even in MacOS. I stopped Docker and boom! Thanks

Comment: running eShopOnContainer app on Linux container,when i run docker-compose build throws error:Unable to load the service index for source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-tools/api/v3/index.json. [/src/eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   Connection refused [/src/eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln]
ERROR: Service 'webstatus' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln"' returned a non-zero code: 1
PS C:\Projects\eShopOnContainers-dev\eShopOnContainers-dev\src>

Answer (score 17):

Just add `--network=host` option to `docker build`

`docker build -t aspnetapp . --network=host`

Comment: If you are running the `docker build` command in a container itself (#containerception), then this will resolve external dependencies as the network is otherwise limited to the container host.  It worked for me when I was running a local task runner using GitHub Actions.  I am not sure if this would solve the problem if you are running the `docker build` on bare metal (or a VM).  Hopefully this helps clarify why this might or might not work.

Answer (score 5):

I got this working by passing in docker build environment variables from the command line like so:

`docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://{un}:{pw}@{proxyhost}:{port} --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://{un}:{pw}@{proxyhost}:{port} -t aspnetapp` .

*note that your username must be url encoded (ei. DOMAIN\name => DOMAIN%5Cname)

Comment: This did not work for me. How did you determine the proxy address and port?

Comment: @Robotron I think you'll need to get that info from your network admin. I posted this some time ago and am no longer at the client where I had to find a solution for this.  Sorry I can't provide more help now, but good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, the problem was a missing dependency used by `NuGet`.

I am using the `microsoft/dotnet:sdk` image, and it works after installing `libcurl3` to my image.

Try adding 
`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcurl3`
to your `Dockerfile` before restoring.

if it doesn't work, try restarting your Docker instance.

`edit`: if that doesn't help you, there is [this open issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5358) on the `NuGet github` where some people are trying to solve the same problem.

`edit2`:added Ignas solution: restarting docker instance.

Comment: Found in the GitHub issue referenced in the answer -- needed to restart my Docker instance.

Comment: 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-ecurity/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden by security policy [IP: 
'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden by security policy 
The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcurl3' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: This didn't solve it for me, but I wanted to say that I needed to use libcurl4 since libcurl3 is old now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm suprised no one said this already.  This was caused by not having the latest sdk installed.  In my case docker was looking for the file

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\NuGet.targets

However this file did not exist on my machine instead I had a different minor version.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\NuGet.targets

I'm sure they're away to get it working using an older version, but in my case I just updated the downloaded the latest sdk

Comment: I seem to have the same thing, but updating my sdk doesn't seem to work for this issue on my side.

Comment: @JelleSchräder, manually navigate to the file its looking for does it exist?

Comment: I found the issue on my side: VPN blocked my requests.

Comment: VPN blocks your request to a local file?

Comment: No, in the dotnet restore a connection with Nuget happens. This connection is blocked by VPN.

Comment: That is perfect, you also need to restart your machine after that

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is caused by your organisation's self-signed certificates, you can fix it by:

1. Get the certificate file (*.cer) provided by your IT department.
2. Copy it into the SSL certificate location: `COPY ["./combined.cer", "/etc/ssl/certs/"]`
3. Update SSL cert list: `RUN update-ca-certificates`

These steps work for Debian, need to be adapted for other distros.

Answer (score 1):

configuring the dns in the docker engine helped me
you go to docker setting then to docker engine you can see a json formatted doc
you add this :

`"dns": ["10.0.0.2","8.8.8.8"]`

then restart docker
i wish that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD or Powershell and run: **dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear**

https://status.nuget.org/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding an explanation to your answer will help others understand how does it help with the problem.

Comment: Also, I don't think this answer applies because the OP is looking for a proxy solution for a Docker environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in `Dockerfile`, I have

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
```

and

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
```

But I only have `.net 2.1` installed (view by `dotnet --list-sdks`). So I have to change `2.2` to `2.1` to make it work.

Comment: I know this is an old one, and I have NO idea why docker would be affected by this when building on OSX, but this did it for me.  I was building with `sdk:3.1` but have `3.0` locally.  Download and install `3.1` for osx and *boom* it works.  WTF, why is docker affected by whats installed on my host!  Maybe dotnet restore is somehow searching localhost first, but by what mechanism I don't know.

Comment: Yes, no way to check is on purpose.  It is best not to assume.

Answer (score 0):

After one hour fighting with proxy, finally following solution worked just fine for me:

```
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://xxxx.com:8080 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://yyyy:8080 -t kdekarin/aspnet .
```

See @patrickbadley's comment for more info!

Answer (score 0):

One more reason why this happens. If your docker file targeting windows container and your docker is running linux mode or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It helps me: Docker Desktop -> Troubleshoot -> Reset to factory defaults

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here (probably due to a self-signed certificate used in the company), and fixed it by adding a simple `curl` to the Nuget URL and setting it to ignore certificate validation just before `dotnet restore`:

```
RUN curl -i -k -X GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Debian 9. I fudge the error with disconnecting from local network. It works for me because I did not change anything on codebase and I do not need to get packages from nuget.

Answer (score -1):

I got this resolved on my Windows 10 Machine by Disabling Avast Antivirus and unInstalling McAffee Antivirus.

- Right click the Avast Icon in the Notification Tab
- Select Avast Shields Control
- Click on "Disable Until Computer is Restarted".

And you can now run the Docker Build Successfully.
I can give Further Assistance if needed.